# Typo3 7.6.22 Bootstrap Package / RTE / unable to use font colors

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

in my current configuration (TYPO3 CMS 7.6.22 Bootstrap Package) the font color picker in RTE does not work. can you help?

I added this TypoScript to PageTSConfig
[image: PageTSConfig]

now it is possible to select colors in RTE
[image: Select Color]

but after saving the page - the color disappiered in RTE and is not displayed in the frontend
[image: Color disappiered]

here is my template configuration.

[image: Static Templates]

Comment: You need to allow the RTE to save style attributes. Can you please give me the HTML you get for the colored text before you save? (You can switch between HTML view and RTE view with the "<>" button.

Comment: <p>Lorem ipsum <span style="color: rgb(0, 204, 255);">dolor sit amet</span>, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et t. </p>

Comment: in my "rtehtmlarea" configuration "basic.allowStyleAttribute (boolesch) " is true

Comment: There are more options which can prevent the style attribute. Have a look in the area `entryHTMLparser_db`. The `noAttrib` option cleans all tags from attributes for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Thomas Löffler!

after changing the pageTSConfig, the format functions are working!

[image: NewPageTSConfig]